# is it possible in javascript to include other characters in jquery.Trim()

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, parsing

i have a string that might look like one of these and i want to display this string on the page but remove all trailing characters (spaces, commas . )

```
var string1  =  "test, test1, test2, test3, ";  
var string2  =  "test, test1, test2, test3 ";  
var string3  =  "test, test1, test2, test3";
```

if i use jquery.Trim() that will work for string2 and string3 but i want a solution that will remove the trailing comman from string1 as well.

what is the best way to do this in javascript, jquery ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with regular expressions.

```
your_string = your_string.replace(/,?\s+$/, "");
```

If you want to use this everywhere you can update `$.trim` to take a regular expression in this manner:

```
(function($){

var old_trim = $.trim;

function trim() {
    switch (arguments.length) {
        case 2:
            throw new Error("Invalid argument." + 
                            " $.trim must be called with either a string" +
                            " or haystack, replacer, replacement");
            break;
        case 3:
            return arguments[0].replace(arguments[1], arguments[2]);
        default:
            return old_trim.call($, arguments);
    }
}

$.trim = trim;

})(jQuery);
```

This pattern is sometimes called [Duck Punching](http://paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/).

Comment: But what if there are two trailing commas? `:)`

Comment: @Šime Vidas -- *chuckles* true ... or multiple semi-colons! If additional characters need to be filtered out then the regular expression can be updated to include them -- @Roland Illig's regular expression is extensible in such a way.

Answer (score 3):

Internally, jQuery.trim uses two variables:

```
trimLeft = /^\s+/,
trimRight = /\s+$/,
```

which is private to the jQuery function so you can't change them (which is a good thing because other code may depend on jQuery.trim working the way it does).

But you can easily make your own trim function with the semantics that you need, even as a jQuery plugin:

```
// your plugin:
jQuery.trimCommas = function(text) {
    return text == null ?
        "" :
        text.toString().replace(/^[\s,]+|[\s,]+$/g, "");
};

// your code:
var string1 = "test, test1, test2, test3, ";
alert($.trimCommas(string1));
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nwsur/

Comment: it will also first see if there is a native trim function on the String object and use that.

Comment: Yes and that's probably why jQuery.trim doesn't take any options to change its behavior because it would mean not being able to use the faster String.prototype.trim

Answer (score 1):

```
var trimmed = "test3, \t\r\n".replace(/[\s,]+$/, "");
```

This is exactly what regular expressions are good for.

Comment: You mean replace? There is no replaceAll in JavaScript.

Comment: Oops. Yes, I do. I probably did too much Java in the last days. :) It's fixed in the answer.